# Python:Changing path at the end of if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sys

My gui currently has a combo box with the the option of selecting four different file locations. Once its selected every file in that directory will be displayed in a listbox:

```
def ComboBox(self, event):
    current = self.buttonChoice.current()

    if (current == 0):
        self.lb.delete(0, END)
        for i in range(0, length1):
            self.lb.insert(END, self.files1[i])

    elif (current == 1):
        self.lb.delete(0, END)
        sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0]+ "\\folder1")
        for i in range(0, length2):
             self.lb.insert(END, self.files2[i])


    elif (current == 2):
        self.lb.delete(0, END)
        sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0]+ "\\folder2")
        for i in range(0, length3):
            self.lb.insert(END, self.files2[i])


    elif (current == 3):
        self.lb.delete(0, END)
        sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0]+ "\\folder3")
        for i in range(0, length4):
            self.lb.insert(END, self.files4[i])
```

However my pathing isnt optimal since the function does not return to the parent directory and is instead stuck in that folder(example if current==1 the directory will be in ...\folder1). To get this working i need to move down one directory at the end of each statement. Ive looked at related question and came across     `os.chdir('..')`. For some reason im having trouble implementing this. Any ideas of how i can move down one directory at the end of each statement.

Comment: how about splitting the filepath and rejoining it like this: `'\\'.join(filepath.split('\\')[:-1])` ? Changing the `1` at the end can move you further back

Comment: @Ev Kounis: `os.path.dirname` does that better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for that! I incorporated it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
example_dir = r'C:\Users\****\Desktop\PythonScripts\ResidualCreation'

def move_back_dir(a_dir, steps=1):
    return '\\'.join(a_dir.split('\\')[:-steps])

print(move_back_dir(example_dir))     # -> C:\Users\****\Desktop\PythonScripts
print(move_back_dir(example_dir, 2))  # -> C:\Users\****\Desktop
```

---

Or as suggested in the comments implement the `os.path.dirname()` in a recursive way as follows:

```
def move_back_dir(a_dir, steps=1):
    for i in range(steps):
        a_dir = os.path.dirname(a_dir)
    return a_dir

print(move_back_dir(example_dir))     # -> C:\Users\****\Desktop\PythonScripts
print(move_back_dir(example_dir, 2))  # -> C:\Users\****\Desktop
```

---

If setting the number of folders you want to go back (`step` in example above) is not required simply do `os.path.dirname(filename)`

Comment: It's @Jean-François Fabre that you have to thank but, welcome

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should be using `os.chdir` and not `sys.path.insert`.

To give you a full answer, one needs to see the rest of your class. More specifically, one must know what there is in `self.lb` and `self.files` and the logic filling it.

Comment: Unfortunately my program is fairly lengthy and pulls several local files